# Retrieve markers as an array from the database using json in android

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I am able to retrieve the markers(Lat&Lng) from my database but I wont to store the retrieved markers as an array and then use it in another activity in adroid

```
 package com.map.driver;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    public class DriRetMap extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dri_ret_map);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Starting locations retrieve task
         new RetrieveTask().execute();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    // Adding marker on the GoogleMaps
    private void addMarker(LatLng latlng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latlng);
        markerOptions.title(latlng.latitude + "," + latlng.longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String strUrl = "http://192.168.43.77/location_marker_mysql/retrieve.php";
            URL url = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
                String line = "";
                while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }

    }

    // Background thread to parse the JSON data retrieved from MySQL server
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<HashMap<String, String>>>{
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            MarkerJSONParser markerParser = new MarkerJSONParser();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = markerParser.parse(json);
            return markersList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            for(int i=0; i<result.size();i++){
                HashMap<String, String> marker = result.get(i);
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lng")));
                addMarker(latlng);
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Comment: from which database server or Lcal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass yout lat and long to another activity, make use of bundles like below,

In activity A,

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString("lat", latitudevalue); 
extras.putString("long", longitudevalue);
```

In Activity B,

```
String lat= getIntent().getExtras().getString("lat");
String long= getIntent().getExtras().getString("long");
```

Comment: I have a list of lat and lng pair I need to pass it as an array,basically fetch it from the above specified activity and then use it in another activity as an array

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you retrieve them in the second activity again or store it in "cache" directory or db? If they are a few maybe it does not worth, but if they are thousands it could be good to avoid too big parcelable stuff.

In any case, when you add the marker to the map, you can save them to a local list (you setup and initialize a list as local variable)

```
List<LatLng> markerPositions = new ArrayList<LatLng> 
// Adding marker on the GoogleMaps
private void addMarker(LatLng latlng) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latlng);
    markerOptions.title(latlng.latitude + "," + latlng.longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
markerPositions.add(latlng);
}
```

You can't pass Marker object since it is not parcelable, while LatLng is.
Then you add the list to the intent as:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)

doing:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("points",markerPositions);
```

and retrieve in the arriving activity as:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String)

```
List<LatLng> positions = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("points");
```

Then you add again new markers to the map or do whatever you want with the positions.
Marker cannot be passed directly because they are tight to their parent map.

Comment: I got what you are trying to explain but it will be helpful if you can explain it through an example or if you can explain what should I do in both the activities to fetch the list from activity a and the utilise it activity b

Comment: The code is all there! The first code block is for creating the list of markers (markerPositions). When you want to start the second activity you add to the intent the list of points as you see in the second code block, then in the launched activity, retrieve the list as in the third code block. You can now do again the code of the first block to add those markers in the map.

Comment: Where in the first activity should i put the intent of the 2 code block and the intent of the 3 code block in the second activity.